# overiding functions defined in a base class with a child class

Tags: c++, inheritance

I am new to C++ and trying to understand inheritance in this language. I have created a `Ship` class, defined some constructors, mutators, and a `print` function that should `cout` some info about the ship. I have two derived classes, one a `Cruise` class and another a `Cargo` Class. The first time I compiled a test of the `Cruise` class everything worked fine. After implementing the `Cargo` class I could no longer compile my code. Both classes are very similar and implemented nearly identically. Here is my code, the error I have recieved is underneath.

#### ship.cpp (defines the ship class)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Ship {
private:
    string _strName, _strYear;

public:
    //Constructors
    Ship();
    Ship(string, string);

    //Mutators
    void setName(string);
    void setYear(string);
    string getName();
    string getYear();

    //Methods
    virtual void print();
};

//*************************************
// Cunstructors                       *
//*************************************
Ship::Ship() {
    _strName = "NONE";
    _strYear = "NONE";
}
Ship::Ship(string strname, string strYear) {
    setName(strname);
    setYear(strYear);
}

//*************************************
// MUTATORS                           *
//*************************************
void Ship::setName(string strName) {
    _strName = strName;
}

void Ship::setYear(string strYear) {
    _strYear = strYear;
}

string Ship::getName() {
    return _strName;
}

string Ship::getYear() {
    return _strYear;
}

//*************************************
// METHODS                             *
//*************************************
virtual void Ship::print() {
    cout << _strName << endl
        << _strYear << endl;
}
```

#### CuiseShip.cpp (cruise ship class that inherits from Ship)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "ship.cpp"
using namespace std;

class CruiseShip:public Ship {
private:
    int _intMaxPassengers;

public:
    //Constructors
    CruiseShip();
    CruiseShip(string, string, int);

    //Mutators
    void setMaxPassengers(int);
    int getMaxPassengers();


    //Methods
    void print();
};

//*************************************
// Cunstructors                       *
//*************************************
CruiseShip::CruiseShip() {
    setName("NONE");
    setYear("NONE");
    setMaxPassengers(0);
}
CruiseShip::CruiseShip(string strname, string strYear, int intMaxPassengers) {
    setName(strname);
    setYear(strYear);
    setMaxPassengers(intMaxPassengers);
}

//*************************************
// MUTATORS                           *
//*************************************
void CruiseShip::setMaxPassengers(int intMaxPassengers) {
    _intMaxPassengers = intMaxPassengers;
}

int CruiseShip::getMaxPassengers() {
    return _intMaxPassengers;
}

//*************************************
// METHODS                             *
//*************************************
void CruiseShip::print() {
    string name = getName();
    string year = getYear();
    string maxPassengers = to_string(getMaxPassengers());

    cout << name << endl
        << year << endl
        << maxPassengers << endl;;
}
```

#### CargoShip.cpp (inherits from ship)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "ship.cpp"
using namespace std;

class CargoShip: public Ship {
private:
    int _intCapacity;

public:
    //Constructors
    CargoShip();
    CargoShip(string, string, int);

    //Mutators
    void setCapacity(int);
    int getCapacity();


    //Methods
    void print();
};

//*************************************
// Cunstructors                       *
//*************************************
CargoShip::CargoShip() {
    setName("NONE");
    setYear("NONE");
    setCapacity(0);
}

CargoShip::CargoShip(string strname, string strYear, int intCapacity) {
    setName(strname);
    setYear(strYear);
    setCapacity(intCapacity);
}

//*************************************
// MUTATORS                           *
//*************************************
void CargoShip::setCapacity(int intCapacity) {
    _intCapacity = intCapacity;
}

int CargoShip::getCapacity() {
    return _intCapacity;
}

//*************************************
// METHODS                             *
//*************************************
void CargoShip::print() {
    string name = getName();
    string year = getYear();
    string capacity = to_string(getCapacity());

    cout << name << endl
        << year << endl
        << capacity << endl;;
}
```

#### TEST.cpp (main() to impliment and test the code)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "CruiseShip.cpp"
#include "CargoShip.cpp"

int main() {
    CruiseShip cruise("cruise", "1862", 25);
    CargoShip cargo("Mellinium Falcon", "a long time ago", 100);

    cruise.print();
    cargo.print();

    return 0;
}
```

#### Compile Error

```
In file included from CargoShip.cpp:3:0,
                 from Test.cpp:4:
ship.cpp:5:7: error: redefinition of ‘class Ship’
 class Ship {
       ^
In file included from CruiseShip.cpp:3:0,
                 from Test.cpp:3:
ship.cpp:5:7: error: previous definition of ‘class Ship’
 class Ship {
       ^
In file included from CargoShip.cpp:3:0,
                 from Test.cpp:4:
ship.cpp:27:1: error: redefinition of ‘Ship::Ship()’
 Ship::Ship() {
 ^
In file included from CruiseShip.cpp:3:0,
                 from Test.cpp:3:
ship.cpp:27:1: note: ‘Ship::Ship()’ previously defined here
 Ship::Ship() {
 ^
In file included from CargoShip.cpp:3:0,
                 from Test.cpp:4:
ship.cpp:31:1: error: redefinition of ‘Ship::Ship(std::__cxx11::string, std::__cxx11::string)’
 Ship::Ship(string strname, string strYear) {
 ^
In file included from CruiseShip.cpp:3:0,
                 from Test.cpp:3:
ship.cpp:31:1: note: ‘Ship::Ship(std::__cxx11::string, std::__cxx11::string)’ previously defined here
 Ship::Ship(string strname, string strYear) {
 ^
In file included from CargoShip.cpp:3:0,
                 from Test.cpp:4:
ship.cpp:39:6: error: redefinition of ‘void Ship::setName(std::__cxx11::string)’
 void Ship::setName(string strName) {
      ^
In file included from CruiseShip.cpp:3:0,
                 from Test.cpp:3:
ship.cpp:39:6: note: ‘void Ship::setName(std::__cxx11::string)’ previously defined here
 void Ship::setName(string strName) {
      ^
In file included from CargoShip.cpp:3:0,
                 from Test.cpp:4:
ship.cpp:43:6: error: redefinition of ‘void Ship::setYear(std::__cxx11::string)’
 void Ship::setYear(string strYear) {
      ^
In file included from CruiseShip.cpp:3:0,
                 from Test.cpp:3:
ship.cpp:43:6: note: ‘void Ship::setYear(std::__cxx11::string)’ previously defined here
 void Ship::setYear(string strYear) {
      ^
In file included from CargoShip.cpp:3:0,
                 from Test.cpp:4:
ship.cpp:47:8: error: redefinition of ‘std::__cxx11::string Ship::getName()’
 string Ship::getName() {
        ^
In file included from CruiseShip.cpp:3:0,
                 from Test.cpp:3:
ship.cpp:47:8: note: ‘std::__cxx11::string Ship::getName()’ previously defined here
 string Ship::getName() {
        ^
In file included from CargoShip.cpp:3:0,
                 from Test.cpp:4:
ship.cpp:51:8: error: redefinition of ‘std::__cxx11::string Ship::getYear()’
 string Ship::getYear() {
        ^
In file included from CruiseShip.cpp:3:0,
                 from Test.cpp:3:
ship.cpp:51:8: note: ‘std::__cxx11::string Ship::getYear()’ previously defined here
 string Ship::getYear() {
        ^
In file included from CargoShip.cpp:3:0,
                 from Test.cpp:4:
ship.cpp:58:6: error: redefinition of ‘void Ship::print()’
 void Ship::print() {
      ^
In file included from CruiseShip.cpp:3:0,
                 from Test.cpp:3:
ship.cpp:58:6: note: ‘void Ship::print()’ previously defined here
 void Ship::print() {
      ^
```

This error makes little since to me and I can't seem to find a solution. The compiler seems to be telling my that I am trying to redifine the Ship class. Can someone explain what is going on?

Comment: Remove the `include "...cpp"` from all the files

Comment: I just attempted your suggestion, but as I would have guessed, Test.cpp now does not know what CruiseShip is

Comment: How are you compiling your code, are you using an IDE or from command line? If so, how are you doing it?

Comment: Have 2 separate files, .cpp having the implementation and .h only declaration. Include both .h files in Test.cpp

Comment: I am compiling on the command line in a bash environment on Ubuntu using the command `g++ --std=c++0x Test.cpp`. The arguement is to ensure I am compiling for c++11

Comment: Shrikanth N Should I do that for all of my classes (both base and derived)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't ever include .cpp files from you're main file. imagine that #including .cpp files are a copy and paste, and you're including the .cpp files in the main, and in the ship files - which results in multiple copies of these copies, and thus the compiler things you have defined it more than once.

You must place the class definition in the .h files - WITH HEADER GUARDS to protect from this duplication, then the implementation details in the .cpp file. Example:

ship.hpp

```
// Protects from multiple copies
#ifndef _SHIP_H_
#define _SHIP_H_

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Ship {
private:
    string _strName, _strYear;

public:
    //Constructors
    Ship();
    Ship(string, string);

    //Mutators
    void setName(string);
    void setYear(string);
    string getName();
    string getYear();

    //Methods
    virtual void print();
};

#endif // _SHIP_H_
```

ship.cpp

```
#include "ship.hpp"    // this .cpp file INCLUDES the .hpp so it can match the functions

//*************************************
// Constructors                       *
//*************************************
Ship::Ship() {
    _strName = "NONE";
    _strYear = "NONE";
}
Ship::Ship(string strname, string strYear) {
    setName(strname);
    setYear(strYear);
}

//*************************************
// MUTATORS                           *
//*************************************
void Ship::setName(string strName) {
    _strName = strName;
}

void Ship::setYear(string strYear) {
    _strYear = strYear;
}

string Ship::getName() {
    return _strName;
}

string Ship::getYear() {
    return _strYear;
}

//*************************************
// METHODS                             *
//*************************************
virtual void Ship::print() {
    cout << _strName << endl
        << _strYear << endl;
}
```

repeat the same for the other files.

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "CruiseShip.hpp"   // include .hpp files. Linker will link the .hpp functions with the .cpp implementations.
#include "CargoShip.hpp" // same here

int main() {
    CruiseShip cruise("cruise", "1862", 25);
    CargoShip cargo("Mellinium Falcon", "a long time ago", 100);

    cruise.print();
    cargo.print();

    return 0;
}
```

To build, you must compile all of the .cpp files separately to ensure they do not have name clashes. They will be linked with the main.cpp automatically:

g++ --std=c++0x ship.cpp cargo.cpp main.cpp   ... etc etc etc

Comment: what is the difference between when you inluded the .hpp file extension and the .h file extention? Should I include `ship.h` in my derived header files? or `ship.hpp`

Comment: you can either use .h or .hpp files, its up to you. In my personal naming convention I use the .hpp extension for all C++ headers to conveys the header uses C++ rather than C (.hpp / .cpp)